# Assign the max value of a group to all rows in the next group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Given the following dataframe:

| col_A | col_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 8 |
| 3 | 9 |

How would I assign the max value of `col_B` from a group in `col_A` to all rows in the next (in ascending order) group in `col_A`? Output desired is as follows:

| col_A | col_B | max_col_B_ from_prev_col_A_group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 2 |  |
| 1 | 3 |  |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 | 3 |
| 3 | 7 | 6 |
| 3 | 8 | 6 |
| 3 | 9 | 6 |

I figured I might be able to get the `max` by group, then `shift` the result forward and `merge` the values back into the source dataframe in some way. However I can't work out the "some way" bit of that solution :(

Any ideas on how to do this? I'm not wedded to my approach at all - just want the fastest solution as there are 1.5m rows and 80k discrete values in `col_A`.

Thanks in advance!

Code to reproduce dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col_A': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 3},
        'col_B': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6, 6: 7, 7: 8, 8: 9},
    }
)
```

Comment: Please, include a minimal reproducible example (including code generating your dataframe)

Comment: Terrible miss on my part! Thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: Well, it didn't stop bitflip :)

Comment: @chrslg Something that might be interesting for you is `df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')`. A lot of people post their df as a table (which I agree, is not the best idea). But you can select the data, press strg+c/cmd+c and then execute this line to read the df. (Doesnt work in all cases, but might help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `merge` with `groupby`+`shift`:

```
(df.merge(df.groupby("col_A").col_B.max().shift(1),
          on="col_A", how="left")
 .rename(columns={"col_B_y": "max_col_B_ from_prev_col_A_group"}))
```